# jQuery Skitter Slideshow overlaps the dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I placed the jquery skitter slideshow just above my dynamic drop down menu bar. When I hover to my menu and another images of slideshow appears, it overlaps the dropdown menu of my site.

Check this site:

I think using z-index css can't solve this problem because my dropdown menu is dynamic and it may have many sub-menus. Is there any code to solve this matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally using z-index should solve your problem, but it's difficult to guess not knowing the site, css and your dropdown menu that's not displaying like intended. But adding a high z-index to the dropdown menu container could work.

Comment: @matthias_h Will you please tell me how much value should I place?

Comment: It doesn't matter how high the value of the z-index is, it just has to be higher than the z-index of the slideshow. E.g. if 100 won't work, just try 1000. In case the site is online just provide a link, just guessing here. And if it won't work, check the z-index value of the slideshow that causes the problem; maybe it could help to set a lower z-index for it than for the dropdown, just to be on the safe side. I admit I don't know the Skitter Slideshow and therefore don't know if the js / css there prevents this approach. Just give it a try.

Comment: @matthias_h No, it didn't work. please check the site: http://pahari.com.np/

Comment: Just updated my answer for the follow-up question re thumbnails at dot navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it out - add

```
#listMenuRoot li {
 z-index: 50000 !important;
}
```

to your listmenu_h.css, works for me.
I just added the !important to overwrite the z-index 1 and 2 that you added for the li.
The highest z-index in the skitter.css is 10000 for the loading image, so everything above 10000 should be sufficient, but just check it out. If it won't work, it would be necessary to check if the skitter - js is setting anything else which I haven't noticed while inspecting in Firebug.

Update for 2nd question in comments (thumbnail images displayed for dot navigation): Just noticed that the values for `position: left` calculated for the skitter `div .preview_slide` and / or the `ul` in this `div` (having the preview-images as content for the `li`, like

```
 <ul style="width: 400px; left: -200px;">
  <li>
    <img src="img/example/001.jpg"></li>
     ....
```

won't match to display your images like intended. Values are slightly off by about 40px. As I noticed at the skitter comments - [Skitter Comments](http://www.skitter-slider.net/comments) - it's possible that you have to adjust the values in the skitter.styles.css for `.box_skitter` and `.box_skitter_large` as the images you're using on your page have a different size.

Skitter CSS:

```
.box_skitter {
  width: 964px;
  height: 300px;
   ...
```

Your images have `width: 960px, height: 330px;` , maybe therefore the positions are calculated wrong.
In case that won't help, you could just write a comment on the Skitter comments page describing your problem, looks like the Skitter authors seems to care about people having problems using their Slider.

Comment: also one small thing when you mouse over the dots, the thumbnail pictures doesn't appear correctly. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Glad that helped you. About the thumbnails - I'll take a look at it, maybe it's just something to add for the skitter settings. When you hover between the dots to the left and to the right, part of the prev./current and current/next image is displayed as thumbnail, so maybe there's just some pixels to add for the skitter css in case it's not possible with the internal settings.

Comment: Ok just a guess - your website uses the skitter version 4.2.3. There was a bug recently fixed in the new skitter 4.3.2. Also the skitter author mentions to use the latest jQuery-version as you already do, but you're including jQuery twice - 2.1.1 in your js-folder and 1.7.1 from ajax.googleapis.com. I recommend you update to the current skitter and, if that doesn't already solve the issue, remove the old jQuery. It's possible that this interferes with some js you're using but just give it a try. Find new skitter here: https://github.com/thiagosf/SkitterSlideshow in js-dir. Hope that helps.

Comment: no it didn't work. The latest version of skitter doesn't work.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. mabybe not that easy to fix - just noticed that the problem is the calculated value for position: left for .preview_slide (calc. by skitter.js). it's not possible to overwrite it with css (even with important it get's overwritten by js), but as it's working on skitter hp it'd be that it's a diff issue. will let you know when I find out something new

Comment: Glad that helped you. Just to be sure - you know that your site is currently not working because you have two closing body and html tags at the end with some js inbetween..?